# Laravel find rows by nested relationship column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables `reserves` and `chats`, `chats` belongTo `reserves` and I want to get all chats where `chat.reserve.user_id = Auth::id()`. How can I do that in laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t know your models name (need more code in question), but try use

```
$chats = Chat::query()->whereHas('reserves', function ($q) use ($authID){
       $q->where('user_id', $authID);       
 })->get();
```

where **'reserves'** your relationship and have field **user_id**. Maybe needed full path to field like *'reserves'.'user_id'*

Also look at [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)